# C++ read from files

Tags: c++

Hello i am beginner at c++ and now just take few test of exams to learn but now i face a problem its kind missing knowledge of c++ , so i have a file with u2.txt and his content is

```
 3 5
Petras Rasa // name of dancer 
3 1 5 8 10 // scores for a technique 
5 6 7 8 9 // scores for art 
Rita Jurgis
6 5 8 5 8
9 8 7 6 5
Rasa Linas
10 10 10 10 10
8 8 8 8 8
```

so task said that the first two numbers shows dancer and judge numbers , second line shows name of dancer the line below shows scores of
technique and one line below show scores of artistry , and so its 3 dancers with  a scores below .

So now i need to write a function witch read that file and stores a scores and names into variables , i am using class and array system , so i will be storing them there , the thing is i do not really know how to read such file because till now i was learning to real a file like Name,54 or so so i was using a getline and end the line with ',' but there is no comma hare so i face a problem hare this is my function till now :

```
const string U2 = "U2.txt";
const string U2rez = "rez.txt";

class Results
{
public:
    string name;
    int scorestech;
    int scoresart;
};


int main()
{
    Results v[5]
    return 0;
}

void Freading(const string fn,Results v[])
{
    int alldancers;
    int alljudge;
    ifstream fin(fn.c_str());
    fin >> alldancers >> alljudge;
    for(int a =0; a < 3; a++){


    }

}
```

so now i need to read this file and count a scores of art and technique of each dancer

Comment: Strong advice: write your programs in English. It's just a good habit to start with. Client of mine had to spend quite a bit of time translating his program from French to English before calling in external help, which would haven't been necessary if he started in English.

Comment: Will edit this now

Comment: By the way, you read the number of dancers `vsokejai` but still wrote the hardcoded value `3` into the for loop.

Comment: yes that because i misunderstand the way i should read that file , do not know should i use for cycle some how or a while

Comment: i could do something like this but not sure if its correct way to do so :     for(int a =0; a < alldancers; a++){
        getline(fin, v[a].name , '/n')
        fin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;
    }

Comment: [Do not read from an `istream` without checking the result](http://kayari.org/cxx/antipatterns.html#istream-check)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const string U2 = "U2.txt";
const string U2rez = "rez.txt";

class Results
{
public:
    string name;
    int scorestech;
    int scoresart;
};

void Freading(const string fn,Results v[]);

int main()
{
    Results v[5];
    Freading(U2,v);
    return 0;
}

void Freading(const string fn,Results v[])
{
    int alldancers;
    int alljudges;
    int biggest = 0;
    int smallest = 99;
    ifstream fin(fn.c_str());
    fin >> alldancers >> alljudges;
    fin.ignore();
    for(int a =0; a < alldancers; a++){
        int biggest = 0;
        int smallest = 99;
        int totaltech = 0;
        int totalart = 0;

        getline(fin, v[a].name);

        for(int b = 0; b < alljudges; b++)
        {
            int scores;
            fin >> scores;
            totaltech += scores;
        }
        for(int b =0; b < alljudges; b++)
        {
            int scores;
            fin >> scores;
            totalart += scores;
        }
        v[a].scorestech = totaltech;
        v[a].scoresart = totalart;
        cout << v[a].name << endl;
        cout << v[a].scorestech <<endl;
        cout << v[a].scoresart <<endl;

    }
    fin.close();
}
```

this is what i done so far but the result i got is :

```
Petras Rasa
27
35

0
45

0
45
```

ware i did mistake or what i did wrong  , because somehow when the loop goes second time it doesn't capture a name of the second dancer

Answer (score 2):

`Rezultatai v[5]`, besides missing a semi-colon, defines a old-style, fixed-length array. That's incorrect, the second number in the file tells you how many judges there are.

Instead, use `std::vector<Type>`. That can vary its length.

And I'm guessing (since you didn't use English) that for this example you actually should have had 3 `Rezultatai`, one for each dancer. Each of those should have 2x5 scores.

Comment: could you give my an example with my code cuz i am beginner and dont really understand use this instead "std::vector<Type>"

Answer (score 0):

Before asking a question like this, you should have search more on this, anyway try the method given in below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void main ()
{
    string line_one_by_one;
    ifstream inputfile;
    inputfile.open ("names.txt");
        while(!inputfile.eof) // To get you all the lines.
        {
            getline(infile, line_one_by_one); // Saves the line in line_one_by_one
        }
    inputfile.close();
    system ("pause");
}
```

What you have to do is identify each line and storing things you need. further read string to int conversion in c++.

read :

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/?kw=string

Comment: [Do not test `eof()` in a loop](http://kayari.org/cxx/antipatterns.html#istream-eof). Also, it's unnecessary to call `close()` on fstreams, that's what the destructor does.

Comment: i am not getting line one by one , i am doing the same as u do but i get a two lines as a name "getline(fin, v[a].name);" and i get a "Petras Rasa 
3 1 5 8 10" as a v[a].name i even try to make a new  string variable as you do in your sample but the result are same